# How can I delete all lines from cursor position using vi

Tags: linux, vi

I have a file in Linux. I want to delete all lines from cursor position till the EOF. How can I do that using vi editor.

Comment: For `vi`, I have upvoted the most appropriate answer below which goes something like `:1,14344d` wherein it deletes everything starting from line 1 and up to line 14344 of a text file with 15,000 lines.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like:

```
:1,$d
```

Replace **1** with the number of the line you're on.

**:** - gets you to command mode
**1,$** - indicates a range from the first line to the end
**d** - the delete command

Comment: On busybox embedded systems `vi` and not `vim`, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Press **Esc** come to command mode

press **v** enter visual mode

**Shift + g** "selects everything from current position to EOF"

**DEL** "delete selected"
```

be careful it can even delete the first line in which case you probably need to do this from the next line in cursor.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** 
Esc -> to enter command mode

**Step 2:** press key d (d stands for delete, vim will wait for second input specifying number of lines to delete)

**Step 3 :** Shift + g (To delete till EOF)

Comment: This is for vim, not vi

Answer (score -1):

Press **Esc** come to command mode

press **v** enter visual mode

**Shift + g** "selects everything from current position to EOF"

**DEL** "delete selected"

Comment: This does not work in `vi`. This only works in `vim`.